# Spurious Missing Scala tool configuration Error under Play 2.4.x

Tags: playframework-2.0, sbt

Documenting in case anyone else runs across this.

As of today no google results on the specific problem.

https://www.google.ca/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=java.lang.RuntimeException:+Missing+Scala+tool+configuration+from+the+'update'+report.++'scala-tool'+is+normally+added+automatically,+so+this+may+indicate+a+bug+in+sbt+or+you+may+be+removing+it+from+ivyConfigurations,+for+example.&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=DkSQVavaMYiN8QeooIDgDQ

So far `clean` has not addressed this.

Will back out and retry as many things as I can but this error just appeared out of no where -- well I was running a specs test in another window and it triggered an update (why?) and that is when problem(s) started.

Will try an `update` next and see if this is a broken update.

Here is stack trace as error occurred.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Missing Scala tool configuration from the 'update' report.  'scala-tool' is normally added automatically, so this may indicate a bug in sbt or you may be removing it from ivyConfigurations, for example.
    at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
    at sbt.Defaults$$anonfun$scalaInstanceFromUpdate$1$$anonfun$6.apply(Defaults.scala:376)
    at sbt.Defaults$$anonfun$scalaInstanceFromUpdate$1$$anonfun$6.apply(Defaults.scala:376)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at sbt.Defaults$$anonfun$scalaInstanceFromUpdate$1.apply(Defaults.scala:375)
    at sbt.Defaults$$anonfun$scalaInstanceFromUpdate$1.apply(Defaults.scala:374)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
    at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:40)
    at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:63)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
    at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:235)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
    at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:159)
    at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
[error] (*:scalaInstance) Missing Scala tool configuration from the 'update' report.  'scala-tool' is normally added automatically, so this may indicate a bug in sbt or you may be removing it from ivyConfigurations, for example.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Missing Scala tool configuration from the 'update' report.  'scala-tool' is normally added automatically, so this may indicate a bug in sbt or you may be removing it from ivyConfigurations, for example.
    at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
    at sbt.Defaults$$anonfun$scalaInstanceFromUpdate$1$$anonfun$6.apply(Defaults.scala:376)
    at sbt.Defaults$$anonfun$scalaInstanceFromUpdate$1$$anonfun$6.apply(Defaults.scala:376)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at sbt.Defaults$$anonfun$scalaInstanceFromUpdate$1.apply(Defaults.scala:375)
    at sbt.Defaults$$anonfun$scalaInstanceFromUpdate$1.apply(Defaults.scala:374)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
    at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:40)
    at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:63)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
    at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:235)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
    at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:159)
    at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

After the first `clean` I got this error

```
[info] Loading project definition from (xxx source directory...)
[info] Set current project to (xxx) (in build file:xxx)
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: play.docs.BuildDocHandlerFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at play.runsupport.Reloader$.startDevMode(Reloader.scala:193)
    at play.sbt.run.PlayRun$$anonfun$playRunTask$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$3.devModeServer$lzycompute$1(PlayRun.scala:73)
    at play.sbt.run.PlayRun$$anonfun$playRunTask$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$3.play$sbt$run$PlayRun$$anonfun$$anonfun$$anonfun$$devModeServer$1(PlayRun.scala:73)
    at play.sbt.run.PlayRun$$anonfun$playRunTask$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(PlayRun.scala:99)
    at play.sbt.run.PlayRun$$anonfun$playRunTask$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(PlayRun.scala:52)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last compile:run for the full output.
[error] (compile:run) java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: play.docs.BuildDocHandlerFactory
[error] Total time: 0 s, completed 28-Jun-2015 3:02:49 PM
1. Waiting for source changes... (press enter to interrupt)
```

After `update` error seems to have gone away. I have other compile errors right now so not 100% sure all is well just yet.

Leaving question up in case stack trace helps anyone else...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`update` appears to have been the magic pill here after all.

Still unsure why it started the process however...

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem while configuring multi-project builds.
Just add `"com.typesafe.play" %% "play-docs" % "2.4.x"`
to `libraryDependencies` or use `libraryDependencies ++= Seq(...)` instead of `libraryDependencies := Seq(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

this happened to me after the computer shut down in the middle of work , i did a clean up from git , and then evolution and it worked again